# Removing rows with the same timestamp numpy

Tags: numpy, duplicates

I have a numpy array of the form

```
TimeStamp  Col1 Col2
0           1    1.2
0           1.1  1.1
1           2    3
1           2.3  3.1
2           2.2  3.0 
3           3    4
```

The final array I want is without duplicated time stamp. For a given timestamp I want the last known value. For instance, the output is

```
TimeStamp      Col1    Col2        
    0           1.1     1.1       
    1           2.3     3.1
    2           2.2     3.0 
    3           3       4
```

I can obviously do this in a clunky for loop. But was curious to find a more elegant numpy solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this:

```
uniq = np.unique(arr)
indexes = np.searchsorted(arr, uniq, side='right') - 1
```

The idea there is to find the places where the value changes.  The result is an array of indexes which you can use for "fancy indexing."  A similar one is:

```
indexes = np.where(np.diff(arr))
```

The problem with that one is it omits the last element.

Or you can have NumPy give you the indexes where uniqueness lies, but unfortunately it only supports returning the first, not the last, so:

```
uniq = np.unique(arr, return_index=True)[1]
indexes = np.roll(uniq - 1, -1)
indexes[-1] = len(arr) - 1
```

Another one:

```
indexes = len(arr) - np.unique(arr[::-1], return_index=True)[1] - 1
```

Here we reverse the input to get the "last" elements from unique, then adjust the indexes at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot John, but I am unfortunately lost here. I took a small example here, I chose a = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,1.1,1.5],[0,1,1],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,3.3,4.4]]) and got uniq = array([ 0,  1,  4,  5, 10, 11, 16, 14, 17]) and indexes = array([ 0,  3,  4,  9, 10, 15, 13, 16, -1]). How do I use them?

Comment: Ahh I think you just meant the first col, didn't you?

Comment: Right, so in that case `a[np.searchsorted(a[:,0], np.unique(a[:,0]), side='right') - 1]`.